# Defining a function that opens a csv file and returns the file

Tags: csv

I have been having a hard time thinking what to do with this code.

```py
def getFile(filename):
    with open (filename, 'r') as reader:
         csv_reader = csv.reader(reader)
         header = next(csv_reader)
    return csv_reader

file = getFile(filename)
list = []
def getpointlist(file):
    
    for line in file:
        name = line[0]
        age = float(line[1])
        number = float(line[2])
        tup = (name, age, number)
        list.append(tup)
```

What I want was to open a file using a function, and then pass it to another function. I always get an I/O operation on closed file error. Ty!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

file= pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter=';')

print(file.head())
```

the result:

```
   name   age test
0  jojo  34.0   ER
1  jojo  34.0   ER
2  jojo  34.0   ER
3  jojo  34.0   ER
4  jojo  34.0   ER
```

Comment: Hi! Ty for your suggestion.  I am just beginning learning python and never used pandas. For this particular code, I was hoping to do it without pandas or any other python library. I appreciate your suggestion though!